# Finding String in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am relatively new to Batch and am having problems trying to find a string value within a txt file. I am using a neat program called CCExtactor to extract closed captioning from a file and need to grab the time of the closed captioning.

The output from CCExtractor looks like this:

```
###SUBTITLE#08:37#08:40#She ran away
```

My batch script looks like this:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (subtitle.txt) do ( echo %1|findstr /R /C:"^[^0-9][0-9]*$" )
```

I can't seem to get this to work! I am trying to skim the time values!

How would I go about doing this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set filename=subtitle.txt
for /f "delims=# tokens=2,3" %%I in ('findstr /r /c:"^###SUBTITLE#[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]#[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]#" %filename%') do (
  echo start=%%I, end=%%J
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for statement, you should make the `delims` value to be `#`.  That way you can echo out `%%d` and `%%e` to get the start time and end time.